# How do I access chromium (or any other browser) cookies

Tags: java, cookies, browser

I have a java application that sends requests to google.com and parses the search results that google returns after query. It worked fine before google didn't started to put capcha for all unauthorized users. And now I am in trouble because to access search result user should confirm capcha. This is my thoughts of how I can get around this:

1. Add JxBrowser to my app but this is too expensive (it costs more than a $1k and to complicated for me to implement)
2. Hardcode my own cookies for google.com but than there gonna be thouthands requests from my acc and I'm hundred percent sure that in such situation google will give me capcha to everyone
3. And the last option (the most realistic) is to ask user to visit google and complete capcha and then somehow access browser cookie

What do I do to make my app work again? Is there anybody with such problem.

Any help appriciated. Thanks

Comment: Well google provides a JSON API https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview?csw=1

Comment: The problem is that it allows 100 searches for free and $5 per 1000 searches. That's gonna cost me a lot of money.. So not sure if this is an option..

Answer (score 0):

After a day of googling and few tries I've finally got the code that can access Chromium and Mozilla cookies. So here it is:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Crypt32Util;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ChromeBrowser chrome = new ChromeBrowser();
        //MozillaBrowser mozilla = new MozillaBrowser();
        args=new String[]{"google.com"};
        if(args!=null&&args.length>0) {
            Set<Cookie> cookies = chrome.getCookiesForDomain(args[0]);
            //Set<Cookie> cookies = mozilla.getCookiesForDomain(args[0]);
            for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
                System.out.println(cookie.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public static abstract class Cookie {

        protected String name;
        protected byte[] encryptedValue;
        protected Date expires;
        protected String path;
        protected String domain;
        protected boolean secure;
        protected boolean httpOnly;
        protected File cookieStore;

        public Cookie(String name, byte[] encryptedValue, Date expires, String path, String domain, boolean secure, boolean httpOnly, File cookieStore) {
            this.name = name;
            this.encryptedValue = encryptedValue;
            this.expires = expires;
            this.path = path;
            this.domain = domain;
            this.secure = secure;
            this.httpOnly = httpOnly;
            this.cookieStore = cookieStore;
        }

        public Cookie(String name, String dencryptedValue, Date expires, String path, String domain, boolean secure, boolean httpOnly, File cookieStore) {
            this.name = name;
            this.expires = expires;
            this.path = path;
            this.domain = domain;
            this.secure = secure;
            this.httpOnly = httpOnly;
            this.cookieStore = cookieStore;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public byte[] getEncryptedValue() {
            return encryptedValue;
        }

        public Date getExpires() {
            return expires;
        }

        public String getPath() {
            return path;
        }

        public String getDomain() {
            return domain;
        }

        public boolean isSecure() {
            return secure;
        }

        public boolean isHttpOnly() {
            return httpOnly;
        }

        public File getCookieStore(){
            return cookieStore;
        }

        public abstract boolean isDecrypted();

    }

    public static class DecryptedCookie extends Cookie {

        private String decryptedValue;

        public DecryptedCookie(String name, byte[] encryptedValue, String decryptedValue, Date expires, String path, String domain, boolean secure, boolean httpOnly, File cookieStore) {
            super(name, encryptedValue, expires, path, domain, secure, httpOnly, cookieStore);
            this.decryptedValue = decryptedValue;
        }

        public DecryptedCookie(String name, String decryptedValue, Date expires, String path, String domain, boolean secure, boolean httpOnly, File cookieStore) {
            super(name, decryptedValue, expires, path, domain, secure, httpOnly, cookieStore);
            this.decryptedValue = decryptedValue;
        }

        public String getDecryptedValue(){
            return decryptedValue;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDecrypted() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Cookie [name=" + name + ", value=" + decryptedValue + "]";
        }

    }

    public static class EncryptedCookie extends Cookie {

        public EncryptedCookie(String name, byte[] encryptedValue, Date expires, String path, String domain, boolean secure, boolean httpOnly, File cookieStore) {
            super(name, encryptedValue, expires, path, domain, secure, httpOnly, cookieStore);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDecrypted() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Cookie [name=" + name + " (encrypted)]";
        }

    }

    public static class OS {

        public static String getOsArchitecture() {
            return System.getProperty("os.arch");
        }

        public static String getOperatingSystem() {
            return System.getProperty("os.name");
        }

        public static String getOperatingSystemVersion() {
            return System.getProperty("os.version");
        }

        public static String getIP() throws UnknownHostException {
            InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            return ip.getHostAddress();
        }

        public static String getHostname() throws UnknownHostException {
            return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName(); 
        }

        public static boolean isWindows() {
            return (getOperatingSystem().toLowerCase().indexOf("win") >= 0);
        }

        public static boolean isMac() {
            return (getOperatingSystem().toLowerCase().indexOf("mac") >= 0);
        }

        public static boolean isLinux() {
            return (getOperatingSystem().toLowerCase().indexOf("nix") >= 0 || getOperatingSystem().toLowerCase().indexOf("nux") >= 0 || getOperatingSystem().toLowerCase().indexOf("aix") > 0 );
        }

        public static boolean isSolaris() {
            return (getOperatingSystem().toLowerCase().indexOf("sunos") >= 0);
        }

    }

    public static abstract class Browser {

        /**
         * A file that should be used to make a temporary copy of the browser's cookie store
         */
        protected File cookieStoreCopy = new File(".cookies.db");

        /**
         * Returns all cookies
         */
        public Set<Cookie> getCookies() {
            HashSet<Cookie> cookies = new HashSet<Cookie>();
            for(File cookieStore : getCookieStores()){
                cookies.addAll(processCookies(cookieStore, null));
            }
            return cookies;
        }

        /**
         * Returns cookies for a given domain
         */
        public Set<Cookie> getCookiesForDomain(String domain) {
            HashSet<Cookie> cookies = new HashSet<Cookie>();
            for(File cookieStore : getCookieStores()){
                cookies.addAll(processCookies(cookieStore, domain));
            }
            return cookies;
        }

        /**
         * Returns a set of cookie store locations
         * @return
         */
        protected abstract Set<File> getCookieStores();

        /**
         * Processes all cookies in the cookie store for a given domain or all
         * domains if domainFilter is null
         * 
         * @param cookieStore
         * @param domainFilter
         * @return
         */
        protected abstract Set<Cookie> processCookies(File cookieStore, String domainFilter);

        /**
         * Decrypts an encrypted cookie
         * @param encryptedCookie
         * @return
         */
        protected abstract DecryptedCookie decrypt(EncryptedCookie encryptedCookie);

    }

    public static class MozillaBrowser extends Browser {

        protected DecryptedCookie decrypt(EncryptedCookie encryptedCookie){return null;}

        /**
         * Returns a set of cookie store locations
         * @return
         */
        @Override
        protected Set<File> getCookieStores() {
            HashSet<File> cookieStores = new HashSet<File>();

            for(String path:new String[]{"\\Application Data\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\","\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\","/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/","/.config/Firefox/","/.config/firefox/","/.mozilla/firefox/"}){
                if(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+path).exists())for(File file:new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+path).listFiles()){
                    if(file.isDirectory()&&file.getName().matches("(?iu)^.*?\\.default$"))cookieStores.add(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+path+file.getName()+File.separator+"cookies.sqlite"));
                }
            }

            return cookieStores;
        }

        public Set<Cookie> processCookies(File cookieStore,String domainFilter){
            HashSet<Cookie> cookies = new HashSet<Cookie>();
            if(cookieStore.exists()){
                Connection connection=null;
                try {
                    cookieStoreCopy.delete();
                    Files.copy(cookieStore.toPath(),cookieStoreCopy.toPath());
                    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                    connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+cookieStoreCopy.getAbsolutePath());
                    Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
                    statement.setQueryTimeout(30);
                    ResultSet result=null;
                    if(domainFilter==null||domainFilter.isEmpty())result=statement.executeQuery("select * from cookies");
                    else result = statement.executeQuery("select * from moz_cookies where HOST like \"%"+domainFilter+"%\"");//ID,BASEDOMAIN,APPID,INBROWSERELEMENT,NAME,VALUE,HOST,PATH,EXPIRY,LASTACCESSED,CREATIONTIME,ISSECURE
                    while(result.next()){
                        String name=result.getString("NAME");
                        String value=result.getString("VALUE");
                        String path=result.getString("PATH");
                        String domain=result.getString("HOST");
                        boolean secure=ChromeBrowser.hasColumn(result,"ISSECURE")?result.getBoolean("ISSECURE"):false;
                        Date expires=result.getDate("EXPIRY");

                        DecryptedCookie decryptedCookie=new DecryptedCookie(name,value,expires,path,domain,secure,false,cookieStore);

                        cookies.add(decryptedCookie);
                        cookieStoreCopy.delete();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
                finally{
                    try{
                        if(connection!=null)connection.close();
                    }
                    catch(SQLException e){}
                }
            }
            return cookies;

        }
    }

    /**
     * An implementation of Chrome cookie decryption logic for Mac, Windows, and Linux installs 
     * 
     * References: 
     * 1) http://n8henrie.com/2014/05/decrypt-chrome-cookies-with-python/
     * 2) https://github.com/markushuber/ssnoob
     * 
     * @author Ben Holland
     */
    public static class ChromeBrowser extends Browser {

        private String chromeKeyringPassword = null;

        /**
         * Returns a set of cookie store locations
         * @return
         */
        @Override
        protected Set<File> getCookieStores() {
            HashSet<File> cookieStores = new HashSet<File>();

            // pre Win7
            //cookieStores.add(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Application Data\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Cookies"));

            // Win 7+
            cookieStores.add(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\AppData\\Local\\Yandex\\YandexBrowser\\User Data\\Default\\Cookies"));
            cookieStores.add(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Cookies"));
            //cookieStores.add(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\nmx4n1pd.default\\cookies.sqlite"));

            // Mac
            cookieStores.add(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Cookies"));

            // Linux
            cookieStores.add(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.config/chromium/Default/Cookies"));

            return cookieStores;
        }

        public static boolean hasColumn(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int columns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            for (int x = 1; x <= columns; x++) {
                if (columnName.equals(rsmd.getColumnName(x))) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        /**
         * Processes all cookies in the cookie store for a given domain or all
         * domains if domainFilter is null
         * 
         * @param cookieStore
         * @param domainFilter
         * @return
         */
        @Override
        protected Set<Cookie> processCookies(File cookieStore, String domainFilter) {
            HashSet<Cookie> cookies = new HashSet<Cookie>();
            if(cookieStore.exists()){
                Connection connection = null;
                try {
                    cookieStoreCopy.delete();
                    Files.copy(cookieStore.toPath(), cookieStoreCopy.toPath());
                    // load the sqlite-JDBC driver using the current class loader
                    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                    // create a database connection
                    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + cookieStoreCopy.getAbsolutePath());
                    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                    statement.setQueryTimeout(30); // set timeout to 30 seconds
                    ResultSet result = null;
                    if(domainFilter == null || domainFilter.isEmpty()){
                        result = statement.executeQuery("select * from cookies");
                    } else {
                        result = statement.executeQuery("select * from cookies where host_key like \"%" + domainFilter + "%\"");
                    }
                    while (result.next()) {
                        String name = result.getString("name");
                        byte[] encryptedBytes = result.getBytes("encrypted_value");
                        String path = result.getString("path");
                        String domain = result.getString("host_key");
                        boolean secure = ChromeBrowser.hasColumn(result,"secure")?result.getBoolean("secure"):false;
                        boolean httpOnly = ChromeBrowser.hasColumn(result,"httponly")?result.getBoolean("httponly"):false;
                        Date expires = result.getDate("expires_utc");

                        EncryptedCookie encryptedCookie = new EncryptedCookie(name,
                                                                              encryptedBytes, 
                                                                              expires,
                                                                              path, 
                                                                              domain, 
                                                                              secure,
                                                                              httpOnly, 
                                                                              cookieStore);

                        DecryptedCookie decryptedCookie = decrypt(encryptedCookie);

                        if(decryptedCookie != null){
                            cookies.add(decryptedCookie);
                        } else {
                            cookies.add(encryptedCookie);
                        }
                        cookieStoreCopy.delete();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // if the error message is "out of memory",
                    // it probably means no database file is found
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (connection != null){
                            connection.close();
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        // connection close failed
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookies;
        }

        /**
         * Decrypts an encrypted cookie
         * @param encryptedCookie
         * @return
         */
        @Override
        protected DecryptedCookie decrypt(EncryptedCookie encryptedCookie) {
            byte[] decryptedBytes = null;
            if(OS.isWindows()){
                try {
                    System.setProperty("jna.predictable_field_order","true");
                    decryptedBytes = Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(encryptedCookie.getEncryptedValue());
                } catch (Exception e){
                    decryptedBytes = null;
                }
            } else if(OS.isLinux()){
                try {
                    byte[] salt = "saltysalt".getBytes();
                    char[] password = "peanuts".toCharArray();
                    char[] iv = new char[16];
                    Arrays.fill(iv, ' ');
                    int keyLength = 16;

                    int iterations = 1;

                    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iterations, keyLength * 8);
                    SecretKeyFactory pbkdf2 = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");

                    byte[] aesKey = pbkdf2.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();

                    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKey, "AES");

                    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, new IvParameterSpec(new String(iv).getBytes()));

                    // if cookies are encrypted "v10" is a the prefix (has to be removed before decryption)
                    byte[] encryptedBytes = encryptedCookie.getEncryptedValue();
                    if (new String(encryptedCookie.getEncryptedValue()).startsWith("v10")) {
                        encryptedBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(encryptedBytes, 3, encryptedBytes.length);
                    }
                    decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    decryptedBytes = null;
                }
            } else if(OS.isMac()){
                // access the decryption password from the keyring manager
                if(chromeKeyringPassword == null){
                    try {
                        chromeKeyringPassword = getMacKeyringPassword("Chrome Safe Storage");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        decryptedBytes = null;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    byte[] salt = "saltysalt".getBytes();
                    char[] password = chromeKeyringPassword.toCharArray();
                    char[] iv = new char[16];
                    Arrays.fill(iv, ' ');
                    int keyLength = 16;

                    int iterations = 1003;

                    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iterations, keyLength * 8);
                    SecretKeyFactory pbkdf2 = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");

                    byte[] aesKey = pbkdf2.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();

                    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKey, "AES");

                    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, new IvParameterSpec(new String(iv).getBytes()));

                    // if cookies are encrypted "v10" is a the prefix (has to be removed before decryption)
                    byte[] encryptedBytes = encryptedCookie.getEncryptedValue();
                    if (new String(encryptedCookie.getEncryptedValue()).startsWith("v10")) {
                        encryptedBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(encryptedBytes, 3, encryptedBytes.length);
                    }
                    decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    decryptedBytes = null;
                }
            }

            if(decryptedBytes == null){
                return null;
            } else {        
                return new DecryptedCookie(encryptedCookie.getName(),
                                           encryptedCookie.getEncryptedValue(),
                                           new String(decryptedBytes),
                                           encryptedCookie.getExpires(),
                                           encryptedCookie.getPath(),
                                           encryptedCookie.getDomain(),
                                           encryptedCookie.isSecure(),
                                           encryptedCookie.isHttpOnly(),
                                           encryptedCookie.getCookieStore());
            }
        }

        /**
         * Accesses the apple keyring to retrieve the Chrome decryption password
         * @param application
         * @return
         * @throws IOException
         */
        private static String getMacKeyringPassword(String application) throws IOException {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            String[] commands = {"security", "find-generic-password","-w", "-s", application};
            Process proc = rt.exec(commands);
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            String result = "";
            String s = null;
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                result += s;
            }
            return result;
        }

    }

}
```